# Online sorting and removing duplicates on two streams of integers

Tags: python, c, sorting, stream, sequence

Suppose I'm receiving two streams of integers. Each stream of integers (1) is not guaranteed to be in increasing order, and (2) occasionally, 1 or more integers will be missing from the first stream but present on the second stream. For example:

Stream 1 - `1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, ...`

Stream 2 - `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 10, ...`

What are data structures and/or algorithms with low space-time complexity for constructing a sorted stream that contains *every* single integer in the union (i.e. duplicates are removed) set of both streams? That is:

Sorted stream - `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...`

Of course, the naive approach is to store every result then sort in O(n log n), making a final pass in a linear scan to remove all consecutive duplicate elements. But this requires a lot of memory and requires both streams to terminate before any processing can start.

This is for a UDP packet sequencer on an embedded device, so code snippets in C are preferable, but I can read Python too.

Comment: Before you begin, you need to understand and quantify two system parameters. 1) How out-of-order can a single stream be? In other words, given that you've seen packet N, what is the maximum value of M such that it's possible that you'll see packet N-M after seeing packet N. In your examples, M is one. 2) How out-of-sync can the two streams be? What is the maximum value of K such that if you've seen packet N on one of the streams, that you might still see packet N-K on the other stream. In your example, K is two.  So that's your first step. Determine values for M and K, and write them in stone.

Comment: If they are all "small" numbers, you could use a bit set.

Comment: A further idea, if they are mostly sequential, you could store an array of the lowest and highest number you've seen in any given consecutive run. For example, you'd encode [1, 2, 3, 4, 7] as [1, 4, 7, 7]. (Representing a run from 1 to 4, then from 7 to 7). If you then encountered 6, you'd decrease the lower bound on the "7, 7" run. Then if you encounter 5, you'd end up merging the two consecutive runs and end up with the entire thing represented as [1, 7]. For speed you should keep the thing sorted so you can binary search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do we know anything about the integers we're getting, or are they just arbitrary?

You're going to need to sort at some point, so I don't see a way to avoid the O(n lg n). Your best bet would be a [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) which is designed for a sort-as-you-go approach. If the value is already there, just don't add it.

(Obviously, instead of sorting, you'd be adding an element to the heap each time.)

Comment: Yes, we don't know anything else about the integers. Both streams are supposed to contain all integers from `1` up to `n`. The integers within a stream are out-of-order with moderate probability and the missing integers in each stream are missing with low probability.

Comment: Why not just have a boolean array of length n. Set arry[n] = true if the number's in the stream. O(n).

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I don't think it is sufficient for what I'm looking for. For example, a good data structure for this should address cache efficiency etc. and heap traversal is slow; and maintaining the entire result in a heap sounds memory-inefficient.

Comment: The boolean array approach sounds pretty good but what if these integers are really just indexes for some structs instead and we need to order the structs in a queue? This wouldn't be online then as we would need to keep all the structs and wait till both streams complete to put them onto the queue.

Comment: Are there limits on how out-of-order things are?

Comment: Hm let's assume the limit is 3,000 positions out-of-order and 1 missing integer on 1 stream out of 1 million.